# python: continue iteration until a certain condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration, do-while, continue

I have a project like the following:

```
my_project:
  |__my_new_data
  |      |__new_data.csv
  |
  |__my_original_data
  |      |__original_data.csv
  |__process.py
  |
  |__read.py
```

I have a function in my read.py that should read data from the data directories in my project, concats them as a panda dataframe and then I import the final dataframe in my process.py to process the data and replace the new_data.csv file in my_new_data_directory

```
from typing import Final

def iteration():
    data= []
    my_new_data = pd.read_csv((os.path.join(my_new_data, 'new_data.csv')))
    my_original_data = pd.read_csv((os.path.join(my_original_data, 'original_data.csv'))) 
    all_data = pd.concat([my_new_data, my_original_data])
    all_data.drop_duplicates(subset="text", keep=False, inplace=True)
    len_first_comb: Final = len(all_data)
    len_iterated_data = len(all_data)
    
    while len_iterated_data > len_first_comb:
        data.append(all_data)
        continue:
    else:
        print ('iteration is finished.')
    return data
```

so, what I would like to happen is this process of combining the new_data and the original data to happen at each process until the len of the new data is no longer larger than the len of the first combination. then the iteration stops
I tried to save the first combination len as a finalized length for comparison, but do not know how to do this comparison iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def iteration():
    data= []
    my_new_data = pd.read_csv((os.path.join(my_new_data, 'new_data.csv')))
    my_original_data = pd.read_csv((os.path.join(my_original_data, 'original_data.csv'))) 
    all_data = pd.concat([my_new_data, my_original_data])
    all_data.drop_duplicates(subset="text", keep=False, inplace=True)
    len_first_comb: Final = len(all_data)
    len_iterated_data = len(all_data)
    
    while len_iterated_data > len_first_comb:
        data.append(all_data)
        all_data = pd.concat([all_data, data])
        all_data.drop_duplicates(subset="text", keep=False, inplace=True)
        len_iterated_data = len(all_data)
    else:
        print ('iteration is finished.')
    return data
```

Comment: hi I have a question, I believe the while loop does not work in the first place because the len_first_comb and the len_iterated_data are the same the first time. is there a way to indicate the second round comparison of lengths?