# python: iteration continues until next comparison meets a condition

Tags: python, while-loop, iterator, iteration, compare

I have a project like the following:

```
my_project:
  |__my_new_data
  |      |__new_data.csv
  |
  |__my_original_data
  |      |__original_data.csv
  |__process.py
  |
  |__read.py
```

I have a function in my read.py that reads the new_data.csv and then I import the final dataframe in my process.py to process the data and replace the new_data.csv file in my_new_data_directory in an iterative process. (corrected code taken from the link below)

> [python: continue iteration until a certain condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464311/python-continue-iteration-until-a-certain-condition-is-met)

```
from typing import Final

def iteration():
    data= []
    my_new_data = pd.read_csv((os.path.join(my_new_data, 'new_data.csv')))
    my_original_data = pd.read_csv((os.path.join(my_original_data, 'original_data.csv'))) 
    all_data = pd.concat([my_new_data, my_original_data])
    all_data.drop_duplicates(subset="text", keep=False, inplace=True)
    len_first_comb: Final = len(all_data)
    len_iterated_data = len(all_data)
    
    while len_iterated_data > len_first_comb:
        data.append(all_data)
        all_data = pd.concat([all_data, data])
        all_data.drop_duplicates(subset="text", keep=False, inplace=True)
        len_iterated_data = len(all_data)
    else:
        print ('iteration is finished.')
    return data
```

so, what I would like to happen is this process of combining the new_data and the original data to happen is to process the data until the len of the new_data is no longer larger than the len of the first combination. then the iteration stops
The problem is that, when I save the length of dataframe, it compares them in the first round and since the length is the same, the iteration never happens. I therefore need to specify the comparison to be made in the next round, not in the first round. so I tried:

```
len_iterated_data = next(len(all_data))
```

but it does not work. is there a way to say next len and not the first one.

Comment: [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) returns an `int` which is not iterable. try putting the `len` of the first combination into a variable and checking each iteration if it is larger or not.

Comment: i actually did that using Final, so the first combination is always fixed, the problem is the len_iterated_data that needs to be compared in the second round and not the first one